# Calculate that at least n number of x values occur from multinomial distribution

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution

Let's say `X` can take on 5 values

```
X<-1:5
```

each of the 5 values occur with some probability:

`p<-c(0.2,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.1)`, where `sum(p)=1`

I would like to get the probability that number 5 occurs at least 2 times out of 3 trials.

For the binomial case I would use:

```
sum(dbinom(2:3,3,0.1))
```

What is the equivalent of this in the multinomial case?

I know that the equivalent command is `dmultinom()`, but I don't understand what the equivalent arguments are.

```
dmultinom(x,size,prob)
```

I don't understand what would correspond to 'at least 2 out of 3'

Comment: Is this for some subject?

Answer (score 3):

1. If $X_5$ is the number of times '5' occurs in 3 trials, you could do it with the multinomial probability function by computing $1-P(X_5=0)-P(X_5=1)$, but to get those probabiltiies you'd need to sum over all the arrangements of the other values. That's a minor nuisance (but it can be done for this small case easily enough).
2. You can do it as a binomial. Note that you either get a result of 5 or you don't, and it doesn't matter for this question which other categories occur. With the binomial, you can do the sum more directly, since cumulative probabilities are available.

So in R you could use `dmultinom` to do it the first way and you could use `pbinomial` to do it the second way.